# The 'System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider' requires a database schema compatible with schema version '1'

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have a SQL Server 2008 DB with many tables filled with data and I used SQL Server Management Studio to generate a SQL dump by using the Script Wizard : Tasks -> Generate Scripts -> Script All objects in the selected database and also selecting the option to Script Data. I made sure to change the value of "Script for Server Version" to "SQL Server 2008". Then I created a new DB and ran the SQL dump on the new DB to generate an identical copy of the old DB. Then I assigned permissions to my default user to the new DB. Then I changed the connection string on my ASP.NET application to use the new DB. But when I run it, it throws the following exception -

```
            Server Error in '/myapp' Application.
            The 'System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider' requires a database schema compatible with schema version '1'.  However, the current database schema is not compatible with this version.  You may need to either install a compatible schema with aspnet_regsql.exe (available in the framework installation directory), or upgrade the provider to a newer version.
            Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

            Exception Details: System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException: The 'System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider' requires a database schema compatible with schema version '1'.  However, the current database schema is not compatible with this version.  You may need to either install a compatible schema with aspnet_regsql.exe (available in the framework installation directory), or upgrade the provider to a newer version.

            Source Error:

            An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

            Stack Trace:

            [ProviderException: The 'System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider' requires a database schema compatible with schema version '1'.  However, the current database schema is not compatible with this version.  You may need to either install a compatible schema with aspnet_regsql.exe (available in the framework installation directory), or upgrade the provider to a newer version.]
               System.Web.Util.SecUtility.CheckSchemaVersion(ProviderBase provider, SqlConnection connection, String[] features, String version, Int32& schemaVersionCheck) +1977772
               System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckSchemaVersion(SqlConnection connection) +89
               System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String& password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32& failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime& lastActivityDate) +815
               System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat) +105
               System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved) +42
               System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password) +78
               System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AuthenticateUsingMembershipProvider(AuthenticateEventArgs e) +60
               System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnAuthenticate(AuthenticateEventArgs e) +119
               System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +115
               System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +101
               System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
               System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +118
               System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +166
               System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
               System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
               System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
               System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you really haven't forgotten anything (views, SP's, etc. etc. etc.), then googling indicates that 'silly' solutions like closing the project and re-opening, rebuilding, or:

*The thing that actually did the trick was going through the ASP.NET Configuration utility (Visual Studio - under Website menu), taking the application offline and then back online. This actually just makes a change to web.config (not exactly sure what the change was). So after taking it offline, I had to upload web.config to the hosted solution. Then took the application back online, recopied web.config, etc.*

May be the answer.

Comment: Again, worked for me. I then published my app to the server after I did this and it is working!

Comment: This is downright bizarre - why does making it offline/online again work? What has changed? TFS says nothing has changed in my Web.config. Perhaps a change has been made in the DB?

Comment: yep - the key seems the change to web.config as you stated.  I simply opened my web.config, added a space, removed that space and hit save.  Started working immediately.  Thanks for a thorough answer!

Comment: Taking it offline and then back online worked just fine for me :)

Comment: @ColoradoRockie: Thanks! It worked for me too, but it's so stupid that it gets fixed just by adding a space to the web.config !!!

Comment: hmmm do anybody knows how to replicate this answer on vs2013?

Answer (score 111):

I have found a very simple way, just paste this data in  the `aspnet_SchemaVersions` table

```
common              1   True
health monitoring   1   True
membership          1   True
personalization     1   True
profile             1   True
role manager        1   True
```

I had to use a few spaces to make the data aligned, ignore the blank spaces

Comment: How the heck... Thanks, Alex. This worked for me. So random. So obscure.

Comment: With this solution there's no need to recompile, just restart the site and it's done

Comment: @arunendra Was my problem, too. Thx.

Comment: This just fixed my problem when I thought I could just drop and recreate the asp tables to "clear" all users, roles, etc for a new application.

Comment: In my case I also needed to restart the application pool.

Comment: It was a month I was confused with this. never thought this could work. +1 thanks!

Comment: VERY nice!  I was thinking I'd have to do something stupid, like delete and reinstall the tables!

Answer (score 41):

I had a similar problem and I was able to solved it adding the default value to table aspnet_SchemaVersions.
This default values were not added to the DB generated using Tasks -> Generate Scripts.

Here a useful [post](http://forums.asp.net/t/985097.aspx/1)

```
INSERT INTO dbo.aspnet_SchemaVersions 
VALUES
('common', 1, 1),
('membership', 1, 1),
('role manager', 1, 1);
GO
```

Comment: I too experienced these values missing after a Task -> Generate scripts.

Everyone should check that they have any values in aspnet_Schemaversions before going down a more complex route to solve this issue

Answer (score 16):

Restarting the app pool worked for me

Comment: To me, it confused my innermost feelings.

Comment: This should have more upvotes - although other solutions address the case when there is missing data, if it is present and all looks well with your tables then turning it off and on again did the trick for me

Answer (score 6):

I am not at all a SQL or ASP.net guru or programmer, got the job by accident, but I had the same issue and the mistake was silly:

In my `Web.Conf` the connection strings would usualy look something like this:

```
<add name="AgriConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=AgriBranch; pooling=true; Connection Timeout=120; Integrated Security=false;Persist Security Info=True; User ID=UserID; Password=PASS***WORD" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Yet yesterday I accidently had my source looking like this `"Data Source=./SQLEXPRESS"`.

And I got the same error as discussed.

This mistake would also explain why when taking the site offline and back online with Visual Studio's utility or when recompiling it would fix the error.

Answer (score 6):

Try updating the web config file with correct version of System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider

You can find the below configuration in c:/windows/microsoft.net/framework/v4.0.30319 or any other version , there you can find config file . Into it check for machine config files
to get version & public key.

For .net frameowork 4.0

```
     <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
     <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SqlProvider" connectionStringName="rolesDB" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
     </providers>
  </roleManager>
```

for .net framework 2.0

```
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
     <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SqlProvider" connectionStringName="rolesDB" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
     </providers>
  </roleManager>
```

Answer (score 3):

You may have to run aspnet_regsql.exe in order to get your schema values populated. You can hard-code the values as well as long as you have all of the generated objects (tables, views, sproc's, etc..

The steps i took to resolve this which worked was:

re-ran aspnet_regsql.exe
ensured the default values where there
restarted IIS.

Then it worked..

But if you just copy the database schema without the values, you need to run 'aspnet_regsql.exe' in order to populate the default values.

the file can be found here (re: msdn):
[drive:]\%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version (it's in 2.0 dir)

and here's some info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: I think this might be the official way, so I went with this and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my case neither of above solutions worked.

I removed applicationName="/" from memnership provider in webconfig which was created by visual studio and then uploaded it to server.

Or you can crate the application row in aspnet_Applications table manually.

Have a nice coding!

Answer (score 1):

I tried many of the options above, but none of them seemed to resolve the issue at the time (although they *may* have helped and I didn't realize it).

The last step I took [that worked] was granting the SQL user in my connection string access to the aspnet_* roles installed by aspnet_regsql.exe.  My SQL user was setup as a db_owner on the database, but wasn't a sysadmin on the box - not sure if that matters.

As soon as I did that, and *after* I'd already tried some of the options above, everything worked great.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your answer to improve its readability.

Answer (score 0):

I first received this error after forgetting to run the aspreg_sql on my new db. Once done I received this error until I shut down Cassini or the ASP.NET development server. Re-ran and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This basically comes when you copy/past complete website solution. ASP.NET configuration for SQL server should be configured separately. Which means you should run the aspnet_regsql from Visual Studio command prompt and follow instruction accordingly during wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but I had an alternate solution.

My connection strings in the `web.config` included `Persist Security Info=True;` in them. Removing this solved the error.